# DHF using Entity-services design of envelope

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I am using DHF with entity-services. I was wondering if an envelope contains multiple entity instances can I have the envelope be designed as below

```
<envelope xmlns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">
  <headers>
  </headers>
  <triples>
  </triples>
  <instance>
        <info>
          <title>target</title>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </info>
        <target:target xmlns:target="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target">
            ....
        </target>
  </instance>
  <instance>
        <info>
          <title>core</title>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </info>
        <core:core xmlns:core="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/core">
            ....
        </core>
  </instance>
  <attachments>
  </attachments>
</envelope>
```

Notice the 2 `instance` tags for 2 instances.

Is this valid, as I was not able to find the recommendation of envelope design, like `xsd` ?Is this a good design of the instances in the envelope or is there a better way ? Or can I have like this

```
<envelope xmlns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">
  <headers>
  </headers>
  <triples>
  </triples>
  <instance>
    <info>
      <title>target</title>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </info>
    <target:target xmlns:target="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target">
                    ....
    </target>
    <core:core xmlns:core="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/core">
                    ....
    </core>
  </instance>
  <attachments>
  </attachments>
</envelope>
```

I want to use the `es` api for canonicalizing the entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the DHF (and entity services) support a paradigm of one instance per document following the envelope pattern.

If you need the same attachments/triples/header support for multiple instances of an entity (or multiple entities) - just split them up and attach them.

Also, you really shouldn't be modifying the instance portion of the generated envelope:

```
<es:envelope xmlns:es="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">
  <es:instance>
    <es:info>
      <es:title>Person</es:title>
      <es:version>1.0.0</es:version>
    </es:info>
    <Person>
      <id>1234</id>
      <firstName>George</firstName>
      <lastName>Washington</lastName>
      <fullName>George Washington</fullName>
    </Person>
  </es:instance>
  <es:attachments>
    <person>
      <pid>1234</pid>
      <given>George</given>
      <family>Washington</family>
    </person>
  </es:attachments>
</es:envelope>
```

But you can add information elsewhere outside the instance as needed. More information on entity services relating to your question can be found here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/entity-services/instances#id_67461

There is, currently, a bit of a gap between ES and DataHub that we are actively working on closing, which is why I encourage you not to modify the default instance setup and keep one instance per envelope document.

Answer (score 1):

For another perspective, I'd say that there's nothing in the envelope design that prevents your approach, particularly the first one.  Some pains were taken to make sure that entity services generates code that concentrates on the scope of the `es:instance` element.

I anticipated that people would design envelopes such as yours.  However, I do not understand what might motivate it.  Please share your further experiences.